# Fast and maintainable way of implementing string to integer lookup table

Tags: c++, string, constexpr, lookup-tables

I can find many hits on the question on how to map an integer to a string constant, with the obvious solution

```
char const* strings[] = {"Foo", "Bar", ...};
```

Now, suppose I want the inverse: I have the string "Bar", and want 1. My strings are up to 4 characters and ascii null is not a valid value. There are 64 integers to map values to. Do I have to write a long if-else construct with string comparison or is there something better.

To clarify, I prefer the solution to not require runtime initialization, which as of C++17, makes ti impossible to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Yes, there's something better: your C++ book will explain the better approach in the chapter that explains how to use the C++ library's `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` templates. This is too long to be fully explained in a short answer on stackoverflow.com, so it's better for you to go over this topic in its entirety, in your C++ book.

Comment: If you know all the strings in advance, you could construct a minimal perfect hash function.

Comment: @Hasturkun How?

Comment: @Hasturkun's answer requires some reading. So hit the books! No one is going to write you the code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My strings are up to 4 characters and ascii null is not a valid value.

With this condition, you can convert your strings into an integer, and use your favourite compile-time integer-to-integer map.

For example, with a `switch`:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

namespace detail {
    constexpr std::uint64_t string_as_int(const char* string) noexcept {
        std::uint64_t result = 0;
        std::uint64_t i = 0;
        for (; i < 4 && *string; ++string, ++i) {
            result |= static_cast<std::uint64_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(*string)) << (i * 8u);
        }
        return result;
    }

    constexpr std::uint64_t operator ""_h(const char* string, std::size_t) noexcept {
        return string_as_int(string);
    }
}

constexpr int lookup(const char* string) {
    using detail::operator ""_h;
    switch (detail::string_as_int(string)) {
        case "Foo"_h: return 1;
        case "Bar"_h: return 2;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I have missed that a constexpr is allowed to go into case labels. This is a really nice technique.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `std::map` unless you need something better/custom.

```
std::map<std::string, int> stringToPos;

stringToPos["Foo"] = stringToPos.size(); // there's other ways to init the map, but you can fill it up this way too
stringToPos["Bar"] = stringToPos.size();
stringToPos["Bleh"] = stringToPos.size();

std::cout << stringToPos["Bleh"] << std::endl;
```

Another option for the filling of the map would be:

```
for(auto s:{"foo","bar","bleh"})
{
    stringToPos[s] = stringToPos.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use c++17 I'd use an `unordered_map` with  `string_view`s. Something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(){

    std::array<char const*,2> strings = { "Foo", "Bar" };
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view,int> map;
    for( int i = 0 ; i != strings.size(); ++i  )
        map[strings[i]] = i;

    std::cout << map["Foo"];
}
```

See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86205f49033118f3):